# TypeScript compile errors with JayData library and JaySvcUtil generated code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013, jaydata

Just started to play with JayData lib. and want to take the benefits of TypeScript.
I've included in my VS2013 project following files:
- jaydata.js
- jaydata.d.ts
- JayDataContext.js, created with JaySvcUtil (v. 1.3.5)
- JayDataContext.d.ts, created with JaySvcUtil

```
1) There is a compile error in jaydata.d.ts, line 2
interface IPromise<T> extends Object {
Error   1   Interface '$data.IPromise<T>' cannot extend interface 'Object':
Types of property 'valueOf' of types 'IPromise<T>' and 'Object' are incompatible:
Call signatures of types '() => any' and '() => Object' are incompatible.   C:\Users\robbin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\scripts\jaydata.d.ts    2   15  TypeScriptHTMLApp1

2)There are a lot of compile errors in JayDataContext.ts beacuse '$data.IPromise' it is not 'used' as generic type
Error   2   Generic type references must include all type arguments.    C:\Users\robbin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\scripts\jaydatacontext.d.ts 1623    16  TypeScriptHTMLApp1
```

I guess I'm missing something trivial but I don't know what.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) The Object interface is defined in lib.d.ts and changed slightly in the latest release with the general tightening up of the type inference system.  Just change jaydata.d.ts so that `valueOf` returns an `Object` and that's solved.

```
interface IPromise<T> extends Object {
    then: {
        (handler: (args: T) => void ): IPromise<any>;
        (handler: (args: T) => any): IPromise<any>;
    };
    fail: {
        (handler: (args: T) => void ): IPromise<any>;
        (handler: (args: T) => any): IPromise<any>;
    };
    valueOf(): Object;
}
```

2) This is caused by the same tightening up.  Before when there was a generic type with no type parameter it would assume any, and now it's an error instead of making that assumption.  The code will work the same if you just make it explicit.  For example:

Old:

```
var x: IPromise;
```

New:

```
var x: IPromise<any>;
```

My understanding if that these kinds of breaking changes won't happen after the 1.0 release.

Comment: Thank you Jeffery.
Modifing the code as you suggested solved the problem. To avoid re-doing same corrections every time I generate the typed data context, I checked the JaySvcUtil sources and turned out that it uses a xsl transformation approach both to generate .js a .ts files. It was simple to modify the 'JayDataContextTypeScriptGenerator.xslt' file to implement the modifications.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad that worked.  You should mark this answer as the solution and optionally up vote it.

Comment: sorry but it seems that i cannot add a vote - my reputationi s below 15