# Error w/ context initialized from JaySvcUtil-generated model

Tags: odata, jaydata

Upon closer examination the file generated together with the .js file built by JaySvcUtil -- in my case called BO_Data.d.ts cannot resolve the two references to **$data.IPromise**. This started happening after I added a new table in the database, regenerated my .edmx model in Visual Studio and then regenerated the entity model with JaySvcUtil.exe.

```
declare module WcfService1 {
export class BOLOEntities extends $data.EntityContext {
onReady(): $data.IPromise;
onReady(handler: (context: BOLOEntities) => void): $data.IPromise;
```

In the console I see this error: *typeOrName requires a value other than undefined or null* 
at this line in my code:

```
window['bolo'] = new WcfService1.BOLOEntities(oProviderConfig);
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I did this, but it didn't help: [TypeScript compile errors with JayData library and JaySvcUtil generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163494/typescript-compile-errors-with-jaydata-library-and-jaysvcutil-generated-code)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I was doing only one of the two things described in [TypeScript compile errors with JayData library and JaySvcUtil generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163494/typescript-compile-errors-with-jaydata-library-and-jaysvcutil-generated-code)

You must:

1) Change jaydata.d.ts

```
declare module $data {
    interface IPromise<T> extends Object {
        then: {
            (handler: (args: T) => void ): IPromise<any>;
            (handler: (args: T) => any): IPromise<any>;
        };
        fail: {
            (handler: (args: T) => void ): IPromise<any>;
            (handler: (args: T) => any): IPromise<any>;
        };
       valueOf(): any;
    }
```

to  etc etc etc  *valueOf(): Object;*

and 2) In your generated typescript file *.d.ts. Change this:

```
  onReady(): $data.IPromise;
  onReady(handler: (context: BOLOEntities) => void): $data.IPromise;
```

to this:

```
  onReady(): $data.IPromise<any>;
  onReady(handler: (context: BOLOEntities) => void): $data.IPromise<any>;
```

where *context:* is your own context.